# MySQL: Performance with Case Statements & LIKE

Tags: mysql, database-performance, data-cleaning

Does Anyone know how to approach for a situation like this

Got 10M records with Business Names & Address which most of them are Dirty and to be cleaned.

Started building Functions using Case statements with LIKE & Regex to find the patterns, problem i am facing was MySQL performance and its very very slow.

Functions does following: Removing extra Spaces, non alpha numeric characters, and standardize the names by using LIKE ( almost got 100 patterns) and i know it will be very slow, but not sure what will be other options for me to try

I am thinking of option like saving all those keywords into a table with respective corrected values and use that table as a lookup to replace keywords using function is that works?

```
punctuation (could use REPLACE; not sure it there are more efficient options)
abbreviations (this is the tough one -- street = st, etc.)
Company/Restaurant/other Names standardizing: Like 
Universities to Univ, CENTER to CTR, AND to &, 
case 
when Businnes_name like '%SUBWAY%' then 'SUBWAY'
when Businnes_name like '%MCDONALDS%' then 'MCDONALD''S'
when Businnes_name like '%MCDONALD''S%' then 'MCDONALD''S'
when Businnes_name like '%STARBUCKS%' then 'STARBUCKS'
when Businnes_name like '%DUNKIN%DONUTS%' then 'DUNKIN'' DONUTS'
when Businnes_name like '%BURGER%KING%' then 'BURGER KING'
```

i got total 100 keywords like above statements in a functions

-Thanks

Comment: The question is too vague. It's slow because it's a full scan.

Comment: Thanks Zerkms .... Thats how the data is. Any suggestions for better alternatives.

Comment: I have seen a resource like http://themanbehindthecode.com/category/development/mysql/
but is it helps?

Comment: The question is too vague. You provided literally no details, so it's not possible to provide any meaningful advice.

Comment: You should provide the query you are using.  Performance questions without queries is, shall I say, rather theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

Data cleansing is best done in a fuller programming language, not SQL.  In a past life, I found that Perl was excellent.

First a few `s{}{}g` commands to clean up some stuff.

Then a `sub` with a hundred lines like
`return q{MCDONALD'S} if $str =~ m{McDonald's}i;`

Then -- *only then* -- store the data into the database.  (You may choose to have a column for the original (McDonald's) and a column for the canonical form (MCDONALD'S).